# Convert Milliseconds into hours

Tags: performance, milliseconds

I'm coding a speeding application that tracks the users speed when they move, I managed to get speed working (distance / time) but the problem is I don't know the right number to use, right now I receive two different times and subtract the intialTime from the endTime when the user moves, I just need to figure out the math so that it is used for km/h correctly.

Right now I have put the time to divide by 100 but I am pretty sure that is wrong

```
  speed = distance / ((endTime - initialTime) / 100 ); //work out speed
     speed = Math.round(speed); //round speed to whole number
  KMHtml.innerHTML = speed; //change html span item
```

Comment: well googling it gives me an answer of 3.6e+6

Comment: You should use jQuery.

Comment: Why? @BrendanCannell

Comment: Well, there's 1000 millseconds in 1 second, 60 seconds in 1 minute and 60 minutes in 1 hour, so... Milliseconds / 1000 / 60 / 60 should give you the number of hours.